# Angular application not loading in the local browser

Tags: angular, command-line-interface

[I have an angular application which is not loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUXPn.png)  in the local browser after I do `ng serve --base-href=\ui...\`. The browser is opening the blank page and doing F12 gave me the information that most of the js files are not getting loaded on the client-side and shows 404 error.

I tried checking those files in my project which showed an error but they are there.
I have to change the base tag Href value-form / to the application URL after localhost like /UI.../

Comment: Run `ng serve` alone

Comment: The files which are not loading and shows 404 on local browser are runtime.js, polyfills.js, styles.js, script.js, ui-toggle.js, jquery.js etc.

Comment: Don't change your base tags.

Comment: Thanks for reply, with only ng serve, localhost is opening and loading properly but it is not helping in opening the page url http://localhost:4200/ui...

Comment: kept the base tag same, as it was.

Comment: You need to add routes to use /ui

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I figured out the issue, the command should be something ng serve --base-href=/ui.../   the href value should be in forward slash rather than backward which I was mistakenly using backward.